# how to improve RF meter?

Tags: rf, detector

On https://www.rfsafe.com/product/diy-rf-meter-led-powered-rf-detector-diodes/ , there is a kit which contains:

- nine 1SS86 Schottky diodes and
- one LED,

which uses to detect mobile phone and microwave radiation.

It states:

> range of application: mobile phone GSM signal. It is useless for PHS, fixed-line telephone,CDMA mobile phone

How can I improve the circuit, in order to detect also cordless phone radiation, like the dect 6.0 cordless phone, which, actually, operates on 1.9GHz?

BTW:when they explains how this circuit works, they using the word germanium diodes, while refering to the 1SS86 diodes. As far as i understand,they are not germanium diodes,they are silicon diodes (silicon Schottky diodes).
Am I right?

Comment: First write specs for desired power sensitivity, min/max range, frequency range , budget, etc accuracy... this board must be next to antenna within mm to work

Comment: you are correct about the diodes they are uhf schottky silicon types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**These people are scammers, and do not deserve your money**

> How can I improve the circuit, in order to detect also cordless phone radiation, like the dect 6.0 cordless phone, which, actually, operates on 1.9GHz?

With this circuit, you can only get exactly one band. I'd suspect this circuit was meant for GSM in the 900 MHz band (they don't mention – could be 800 MHz or 1800 MHz, too, one reason more to stay away from that product).

The circuit itself is kind of funny: it's two things in one:

- a loop antenna (hence the circular layout)
- a voltage multiplying diode cascade, which I can only guess works by exploiting parasitic capacitance.

This device will not work. Even if we assume the LED gets this bright with but 0.5 mA (it will not), a single 1SS86 would have a forward voltage of about 0.18 V; nine of them in series would have a forward voltage of 1.62 V. Then add the forward voltage of the LED (something around 2V). Without a *very* large antenna, you cannot get peak-to-peak voltages that high from an EM field as weak as legal for GSM.

I tried to watch the video, but it was so full of bullsh*t that I couldn't stand to finish it. Don't buy anything from these people. If you put your cell phone in something that tries to block electromagnetic radiation, you will be subject to more energy, not less.

One thing that struck me was: in the assembly instructions, there was no external antenna whatsoever, whereas in the video where they demonstrate this thing lights up, the have about 15cm of wire attached to the device. **That's a scam.** Not only doesn't the device work on its own, it's almost certain they can now use whatever secondary transmitter (and by the length of that cable, maybe a 433MHz analog FM radio transmitter that can send 100s of watts – much much much more than cell phones) to light up the LED.

Comment: So,there is no way to talk about circuit improvment.

Comment: @xchcui in the sense that improving something inherently broken is impossible, yes.

Comment: So,i understand that there is no way to talk about circuit improvment,while you said that it won't work even with mobile phone.I,even,tried before,one of the circuit that,F. Bloggs,attached(http://www.creativescience.org.uk/mobile_LED.html).I built the first simple circuit,next i built the one at the end of the page with the darlington pair amplifier and improved it to Sziklai amplifier.No-one of the circuit works!.If you bypass the antenna and provide the first transistor base ~1V,the amplifier works,but the antenna,by itself,didn't detect nothing,whatever length of wire i attached.

Comment: So,I don't know at which circuit i can trust,that it will really work.

Comment: that's because such a circuit will be very complex. cell phones can still work with extremely little power, and detecting that reliably without having constant false alarms is pretty much impossible.

Comment: You had mentioned at your response to F.bloggs,that a simple circuit with transistor amplifier can be built with spending,even,less money,that can detect the mobile phone radiation(the little power,i guess).May you give an example?But,that it will work;)

Comment: No, that will **not** work, but it would still be better than what they do. And cheaper. Don't try to argue with me over physics! I can't change them. A GSM phone needs to work with signals as low as -90dBm, that is \$10^{-12}\$W. To light up an LED, you need more than 2V @0.5mA = \$10^{-3}\$ W. You need something that amplifies by a factor of *one billion*. But that something will then be extremely sensitive to every kind of interference, so you need filters with very high Q. This is nothing that you can just build yourself from scratch.

Comment: I didn't see any attached circuit to your last reply.Did you mean,that even if you will attach your better built circuit,it won't detect the mobile phone radiation(turn-on the led)?And it will be waste of time to built all those kind of circuit which found in the net for that purpose?I really was hoping to built a one that will work.

Comment: RF isn't that easy, sorry. You can build an easy AM Radio detector out of an antenna, a diode and some display, but you can't do that with microwaves like GSM signals that easily, and they are much, much more delicate. Your best guess is to get into SDR: spend 20$ on an RTL-SDR and observe the spectrum! you'll see much better what's happening there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you're right, this is a silicon Schottky diode, nothing to do with Germanium. Stay away from their products, they don't seem to understand what they're doing.

EDIT: OMG, "LED light bulb". Seriously?

Comment: They also misspelled DIY as DYI in the video title, so meh.